# Imagemagick crop svg issue : Lost all colors

Tags: javascript, svg, imagemagick

I've a strange issue using imagemagick on SVG.

I wanted to crop a svg generated with Rapahel.js with imagemagick with this command :

```
convert -crop 100x100+200+150  63ce0a697bc5927d3541215c62b06cfb.svg winners/exhb2.svg
```

But

1. I lost all colors, I just have a Black ans White image
2. My file was 145.6Kb then became 583.8 Kb`after convert methode (Mogrify does the same)
3. Instead of using path the image is generated with circle (oO ?!)
4. Obiwan Kenobi

Does anyone understand why?

Comment: What's the source file look like? Perhaps you're defining the colours in an external stylesheet and imagemagick can't load that stylesheet.

Comment: If you don't need to remove any elements doing this should just be a matter of changing the `viewBox` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem : imagemagick does not support SVG :P
I have to use inkscape for every svg manipulation !
Problem solved partially :P